# rCharts : Highcharts column with color based on value

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I'm trying to plot efficiency in column plot with highchart.

```
data <- c(25,50,75,100)
a <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
a$chart(type = "column")
a$data(data)
a
```

[image: normal rchart highchart plot]

is it possible,using rcharts to obtain below chart 
[image: required plot]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [colorByPointer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.colorByPoint) parameter

Comment: this seems to be using the points **x** value rather than the **y** value, how can I get it to use the y value?

Answer (score 1):

This will change the color of each column in your series. Obviously, you can choose whichever color you want.

```
values <- c(25,50,75,100)
vcolor <- c("orange", "green", "blue", "red")

a <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
a$chart(type = "column")
a$series(data = list(
  list(y = values[1], color = vcolor[1]),
  list(y = values[2], color = vcolor[2]),
  list(y = values[3], color = vcolor[3]),
  list(y = values[4], color = vcolor[4])
), name = 'Data')
a
```

Carlos